# Why is svchost.exe terminating my C# application?

Tags: c#, windows, silent, termination

For some reason, my C# application is being terminated by svchost.exe and I'm trying to understand why.  It was terminating the application silently until I turned on Silent Process Exit logging using Gflags.exe from the Windows Debugging Tools.  It happens infrequently on machines that I can't running debugging tools on (customer pcs).

The event doesn't really provide me with much info to go on.  The termination code is 805306369=0x30000001, but I can't seem to find anything useful online that would tell me how to interpret that number.

I was hoping that the Silent Process Exit log would shed some light on this, but now I just have more questions.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Here is the event in question:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-ProcessExitMonitor
Date:          06/05/2013 04:12:17 PM
Event ID:      3001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      PC
Description:
The process 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\MyApp.exe' was terminated by the process 'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe' with termination code -805306369. The creation time for the exiting process was 0x01ce61ad4e81c70c.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-ProcessExitMonitor" Guid="{FD771D53-8492-4057-8E35-8C02813AF49B}" EventSourceName="Process Exit Monitor" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">3001</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-06-05T20:12:17.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2350</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="xxxxx" />
  </System>
  <EventData Name="EVENT_PROCESSTERMINATION_CROSSPROCESS">
    <Data Name="param1">C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\MyApp.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">-805306369</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">01ce61ad4e81c70c</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Could this be machine shutdown where you're being forced to shutdown because you didn't react to the shutdown message fast enough?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I can tell from the logs that the computer is not being shutdown in any of the instances that I've seen so far.

Comment: `svchost.exe` does a lot of different things, so the first thing to do is to use Task Manager to work out which actual service the process ID corresponds to.  (Since the PIDs are different on each run, you need to do this before the machine is rebooted, and preferably as soon as possible after the error occurs.)

Comment: I don't actually see the process id for the specific svchost.exe process in the event.  There are the event id and the evernt record id, but that seems to be it unless I'm missing something obvious (wouldn't be surprising). Thanks.

Comment: @Mike did you ever find the cause of this? We are having similar issues with an application being terminated by `svchost.exe`.

Comment: I have the same issue. Does anyone found why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I put this same response in similar thread: [Why would svchost.exe terminate my process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367153/why-would-svchost-exe-terminate-my-process)

svchost.exe is exactly what the name states ( hosts a service ) and is the parent/container for services that are registered/listed in services.msc ( as main interface most are familiar with ).

Windows Error Reporting has a hosted service that is listed as "Windows Error Reporting Service" as the Service Name however the actual CommandLine that is sent upon service starting will pass "WerSvcGroup"

In order to see what the actual Service/Process name that is being hosted , the easiest way is to just open a cmd (or powershell) and type tasklist /SVC The output will be the name of the hosted service and the ProcessId that you can use to reference back to task manager or whereever applicable..

I have had to reverse engineer and set up traces to try to figure the same information when I first started working with Silent Process Monitor and one bit of advice I can give is if you select the option to perform a dump file, it will generate a dump of the process that was killed and also do a dump of the process that killed/terminated and if you open the dump file of the SvcHostxxxxx.dmp , just do a !peb and you can look for the command line of process and if it is Windows Error Reporting you would see this in the debugger's !peb output

ImageFile:    'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe'
CommandLine:  'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k WerSvcGroup'

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. SO is a Q&A site and answers should actually answer the question. Had someone asked how to troubleshoot service crashes, this would be an acceptable answer (although there are better tools and no need to reverse-engineer anything)

Comment: In this case though svchost isn't the source of the error. `svchost` runs the service that monitors for silent termination, that's why it's mentioned as the source. Service troubleshooting won't show why a desktop application terminated silently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   The title/question is "Why is svchost exe terminating my csharp application" ...  which is exactly what I answered....    the "svchost" that is listed as the offender in the Silent Process Exit monitoring  message is most likely going to be hosted service that handles the Windows Error Reporting mechanism..  WER does in fact kill the process after it has finished its work and thus , is the culprit

I further explained how you can easily get more information on the generic "svchost" because it very well could be another hosted service that decided to kill a process.

Comment: I have had a few cases where .net  application just shuts down with 0 event log entry which is very rare since the OS / CLR will attempt to write something about a crash.. 
I used Silent Process to try to figure out if the client was self terminating or if AV / External process was involved and the helpful message I saw was generic Svchost  killed it..
that is whaty I "reversed engineered" and set up tracing to see how the silent process exit worked and how could I get more info about a process that was involved in terminating client.  
WerFault.exe does SileptProcess Reports and Dumps