# Why would svchost.exe terminate my process

Tags: c#, windows

MyApp.exe is WPF C# application. It is started from the shortcut on the desktop. Sometimes the application is terminated silently. After I enabled Silent Process Exit from the Debugging Tools, I found this event in the Event Viewer.

`The process 'C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe' was terminated by the process 'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe' with termination code -805306369. The creation time for the exiting process was 0x01d6a237dcb58efc.`

Why would svhost.exe terminate my process?

Comment: Event viewer event looks exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992011/why-is-svchost-exe-terminating-my-c-sharp-application

Comment: What's *"svhost.exe"*?

Comment: 0xCFFFFFFF == "Process was unresponsive and was terminated".  How the service host got involved is hard to guess, WPF does have a scary back-end and anti-malware is never not a problem on a dev machine.  It is bad news, you can't trust that machine.